# Any idea how to plot something like this "Oncomap"?

Tags: r, plot, statistics

Good day everyone,

I ran across the following plot, that I would like to recreate using my own data with R:
[image]

Do you have any idea how to do something like this? In the published article (which is open-access) the author employed R too, so I thought I might try as well. Thing is, I don't even have a clue which package to use or how to integrate that much information into a heatmap and match different observations to each other in that kind of way...and I do admit that I'm still a beginner when it comes to R in general.

Should anybody have an idea (and the time to answer of course), please let me know - I'm grateful for any kind of help!!

Comment: If the paper is open access, then the code to recreate the plot may be available in the appendices of the paper (perhaps editing your question and including a link to the original paper might help, since I can't find it with a reverse image search on Google). I think if I were going to reproduce this plot I would use the ggplot2 and ggnewscale packages. Perhaps also patchwork. If you want more specific advice than this, please include reproducible data in your question, ideally using the output of `dput(df)`, where `df` is the name of your data frame. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an R package to create these plots; perhaps http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/maftools/inst/doc/oncoplots.html? Or maybe https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/oncoprint.html#apply-to-cbioportal-dataset? If those don't give you what you want you might want to search google for similar alternatives

Comment: That looks just like the right package I need! Thank you very much! I'll try to figure it out with this and should I run into problems, I'll come back to either this thread or post a new question. And unfortunately, the code is not included in the publication...